# How is this statement including an if statement evaluated?

Tags: python

Suppose that I have the following Python Code:

```
def fun5(a, b, c):
    return a <= b if b <= c else False
fun5(2, 4, 6)
```

The output of `fun5` is `True`. How is this code being evaluated by Python?

I was expecting a `SyntaxError` because of the lack of indentations and Python requires indentation.

Comment: Indeed, it isn't a statement, it is an expression!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking at is called a [conditional expression/ternary operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/), and it is perfectly valid syntax.

It's equivalent to:

```
if b <= c:
    return a<=b
else:
    return False
```

Comment: It's also equivalent to `return a <= b <= c`